# Good approch to design project that uses different type of Databases in single project

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Suppose that my project uses 3 different databases MySql, Redis, Cassandra. I want to generalized my design so that

1. It will return respective database client based on input type at run time (similar to factory design pattern)
2. In Future, i can easily add or replace DB without much code changes

Something like this, suppose at run time if i want to read/update mysql db my design should return mysql db connection form connection pool, now i want to do same for Redis so based on input it should return Redis connection from connection pool.

Can any one please suggest me the best approach that i should follow to design my project?

Answer (score 0):

There's no silver bullet for these kind of things, but it's good that you're thinking ahead on this. What you need to do is to isolate those databases from your code logic so the code is agnostic to which storage data is going to or from which storage the data is coming from.

1. Factory pattern will help you to come up with which concrete implementation of your abstraction you need to use during your code execution. I think you're in the right track here. I'd also evaluate if you have a way to set this up via configuration (do you really need to decide at run-time or you can infer it earlier).
2. In order to easily switch implementations, the most common technique is [Dependency Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). Simplified, what it means is to abstract a common interface for your dependency (in this case, the database) and do all your client code against that interface. This way, if you decide to swap the concrete implementation behind your interface, your client code would not need to change. Happy days!
   In terms of databases, I'd probably segregate those interfaces into two (read/write) because you might not be able to come up with 100% compatible interfaces between them.

Answer (score 0):

A good candidate for

> return respective database client based on input type at run time and can easily add or replace DB without much code changes

is the [Strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). It defines a family of (in your case DB) algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them interchangeable at run time. Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it.

[image: DBStrategy]

Answer (score 0):

[DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)s injected by an [IoC (DI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container.

This way the business services (which are clients of the DAOs) are not concerned with data access logic details.